# How to terminate wpa_supplicant before selecting reboot

Tags: debian, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I jave just installed Debian 9 on a computer that needs non-free firmware files for the wifi adapter following this instructions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336533/installing-missing-firmware-in-debian

When I power-off the computer, the wifi adapter works fine when the computer is later powered on.

However, when I reboot the computer, the wifi adapter is not recognized by Debian.

I read in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/770488/could-not-set-interface-wlan0-flags-up-input-output-error-rt3290   that "the driver rt2800pci needs to unload firmware from the device which persists during reboot", so I unloaded it executing:

`rmmod rt2800pci`

but the system still does not recongnizes the wifi adapter.

I tried killing wpa_supplicant with teh following command:

`wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate`

And the wifi adapter was recongized when rebooting the computer. Therefore I would like to configure the system so it runs this command (wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate) when I choose to reboot the system (instead of powering it off and on again).